# Stackable items: what's the point of an item not stacking to infinity?

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics, inventory

Pretty much every inventory system that doesn't care about realism and still let's you carry thousands of useless items in your pocket will anyway decide to give items a maximum stack size. Which is usually quite arbitrary if not small: 8, 16, 32, 64...256...999 and so on.

Why not just make it infinite and simply shorten the integers that are to large with 2 numbers and 1 letter? Like once you got 3 billion and a half berries you gathered for some tedious useless question, it can just say "3.5B berries"?

Answer (score 4):

For starters, there are technical limitations, as there is a hard limit on how much value an variable can contain. (The limit of an int is 2,147,483,647. Which is roughly 2,14 Billion)

Then there are also intentional gameplay limitations. For example: If you had an unlimited stack of cheese, then you also never have to worry about running out of cheese, or healing items. Then there is also no value in carrying other items.

Inventory management and limitations depends from game to game.
Terraria for example had once a limit of Health potions of 30 per stack, but you have a lot of inventory slots. So you could just use up more inventory slots for more space. through the updates this has been increased to 99, 999, and finally also 9999. At first sight I found it rather overwhelming, as almost anything past the 999 is already more than necessary. But Terraria has become a large game with tons of different items that fills the inventory, and some of these items reach the 999 cap pretty quick.
Other games like Fire Emblem have a much more strict inventory system, like 3 healing items per slot, where it's usually only 5 slots per character. Even the weapons have a limitation of uses, so more care has to be put in choosing the available options.

More limitations helps to give you more choice, which leads to a larger risk/reward system, "Should I carry this reviver or this damage boost? Should I store away items I don't use?"

Limits between these stacks can also give you a hint on how often you're going to use them. "9999 bullets, I guess I'll go through them fast", "5 mega blasts, I guess I'll be careful with them".

The higher a number is, the less value you'll see in the amount, the easier it would be to lose more. A larger limit won't really solve the problem, it'll only make things less clear. If you already have 999 'useless' items, then you already have more than you'll ever need. The max stack here actually helps to tell you to do something about it.

As for the 'arbitrary numbers', Minecraft uses a stack system that is always multiplied and dividable by 2 (2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 ect.), not only is this useful for building, but also for splitting item numbers in half.

And finally: If there's an infinite amount of resources, then it's no longer a resource. As care doesn't have to be taken into consideration.